# best online place to buy DAW's and plugins for the uk?

Tags: online, purchase-advice

Looking to get DAW's, plugins, synth packages, midi keyboards, and maybe sound libraries.

Please recommend your favourites.

Much obliged.

Answer (score 1):

For plugins audiodeluxe I suggest you Audiodeluxe.com, when you create an account (free) you get a lot of special offers!

Answer (score 0):

I bought Pro Tools from [morecomputers.com](http://www.morecomputers.com) for a very good price, cheaper than any music specialist etc I could find and they had it in stock where everywhere else had waits for stock to come in. I even paid for 3-5 day delivery, but got it next day! Very impressed with their service, was even better than highly respected stores like GAK and Andertons.

EDIT: Forgot to say, I bought Pro Tools 9 + MBox, with free Pro Tools 10 Upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

dv247.com does the job but can sometimes be annoying, for example on of my friends bought Pro Tools 9 (around the time 10 was announced) and they wouldn't ship it because they ran out of copies (the site said they were still in stock) and instead of ordering the "last" batch of Pro Tools 9 software from Avid, or whoever ships them they said they were waiting until Pro Tools 10 started to ship. Which was around a month away. It was also delayed further because they ran out of that first batch before it came to my friends order so they had to wait around another two weeks.

Other than that one time all my friends have had a great service with them and have had no complaints. I personally haven't shopped there so I can't have a say in it, just passing on an experience I know of.

I live close to a physical music specialist shop, Soundslive. So I don't tend to buy much online but there online store soundslive.co.uk is run by the same guys not some other company. I have had great service from them, they know their audio gear. I don't know about delivery times and such but they are based in the north east so you lot down south may get longer delivery times.

Plugins wise I usually just go straight to the source.